# Go linter in VS code not working for packages across multiple files?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, golint

I have installed the Go extension (version 0.11.4) in Visual Studio Code on MacOS:

[image]

However, I find that the linter does not 'pick up' functions defined in the same package, but in different files. For example, if I create in the same directory a file `foo.go` with

```
package foobar

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SayHello())
}
```

and a file `bar.go` with

```
package foobar

func SayHello() string {
    return "Hello, world!"
}
```

then in `foo.go` I get a linter error that `SayHello` is an `undeclared name`:

[image]

I've read about a similar issue here (https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/57), but since that issue is five years old I figured it might be fixed by now? Or does `golint` simply not work across multiple files?

Comment: BTW, that's not a linter error--it's a compilation error.

Comment: Which lint tool you're using? `golint`, `golangci-lint`, other?  Check  settings `go.lintTool`  then try to run linter from command line.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 71):

I faced same problem. I found that I got into this problem after enabling "Go language server" which is an experimental feature. I disabled it in VS code settings->Go Configuration and after that the problem went away.

Comment: 2022(almost) update: I actually had to install Go language server for it to start working...

Comment: Disabling and then re-enabling worked for me..

when i disabled VSCode for go no longer understood "package main", so had to re-enable it

Comment: My problem was that, without changing it myself, the "go.lintOnSave" setting had been changed globally to "file" instead of "package". Maybe a bad old config from a previous version that got ported over? It seems "package" is supposed to be the default.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I went through everything in the updated answer, however what ultimately fixed it was disabling the "Go: Language Server Experimental Features" setting.

Answer (score 64):

Update VS Code Go Tool might help.
`Command + Shift + P` -> `Go: Install/update tools`
Install all tools and restart VS Code.

---

May 2022 update:

This solution only works if you haven't installed the `helper tools`. Normally after you installed these packages it'll work right away with the `default configuration`, if you still have a problem, take a look at the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485684/6678419).

Comment: It is worth noting that I had installed/uninstalled the Go extension and checked the language server was enabled, but I was still having issues until I manually updated the VS Code Go Tools.

Answer (score 35):

The cause of this warning for me was the setting `go.lintOnSave`, which was set to `file`. Changing the value to `package` made the linter correctly pick up the types defined in other files.

Comment: This solution was the correct one for me. **Use Language Server** was already unchecked on mine and updating _go_ tools did not work for me.

Answer (score 11):

The plugin has changed a lot since 2019.

- In 2021, Go Module became the default which may have changed how the program is built and analyzed.
- The vscode-go plugin uses `gopls` as the language server by default. Note that in 2019, there were two different language servers and `gopls` was still in experimental mode.
- `golint` was deprecated.

If you still have a similar issue, it's likely that you are seeing a different problem.

Please check the followings:

- Do you have `go.mod`? Otherwise, [initialize your working module](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Initialize_new_module_in_current_directory) and restart the language server or reload the window.
- Is the `go.mod` file in the root directory of your workspace? See [`gopls` workspace setup
  guide](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md) for complex setup.
- Do you use [build tags or other build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints)? Then see [issue 29202](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29202). You may need to configure `"go.buildTags"` or `"go.buildFlags"`.
- If you expect lint errors from linters like `staticcheck`, `golangci-lint`, ..., check [`"go.lintOnSave"`](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#golintonsave) is set to the right scope.

If you notice that restarting the language server ("Go: Restart Language Server" command) fixes your issue, that's a gopls bug. Please consider to file an issue in github.com/golang/vscode-go following [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#collect-extension-logs).

Answer (score 9):

1. Update Install/update tools for GO
2. Open your code as main project in VS Code and avoid multiple projects/workspace in the same VS Code.
   **

> Single Project VS Code

**
[image: Single Project VS Code]

**

> Avoid Multiple Project in VS Code

**

[image: Avoid Multiple Project in VS Code]

Answer (score 3):

If you run across this and are NOT using modules, then adding "go.useLanguageServer": false will disable gopls and return you to your former environment.  (meaning vscode will now recognize functions and structures defined in multiple files in the same package)

Comment: What if we are using modules?

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a missing `go.mod` file. I fixed with the following command:

```sh
go mod init example.com/myProject/myModule
```

Of course you should use a more reasonable module name.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason:

If you are referencing a function/variableis declared in a test file **(*_test.go)** from a non test file, this error would be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Make clean uninstall of vscode and then it's work fine again...

**add sudo if you needed to**

```
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code

rm -rf $HOME/.vscode
```

Remove vscode from application

Download vscode and install again

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue by having the go extension installed, and attempting to utilize the same package name with a module under a different directory.

- Files at Root: `main.go`, `a.go`, and `go.mod`
- Sub-directory: `nested/b.go`

Problem: Attempting to label `b.go` as `package main` when it is under a different directory.

Solutions:

1. Move `b.go` up to project root and retain package name; all works as expected,

- or

2. Change package name of `b.go` from `package main` to `package nested`, then add imports for `b.go` to `main.go` via:

```
// main.go
package main

import "example/nested"

func main() {
    A()
    nested.B()
}
```

and `b.go`:

```
// b.go
package nested

import "fmt"

func B() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from B")
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just restarted VS Code and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here do not cover the `buildtag`s scenario. The error messages do not do a good job pointing to this. If none of the other solutions work out, it might very well be that a module you're using uses a build tag. Search your codebase (`cmd + shift + f` or the magnifying glass icon on the left bar) for `//go:build`. In my case I had a:

```
//go:build linux
```

and this was the root of my problems. To make `gopls` aware of this, you must add the following configuration to settings.json

```
{ //your settings.json
  //...,
  "gopls": {
    "build.buildFlags": ["-tags=linux"],
  },
  //...
}
```

note your build flag may be different so replace `linux` with whatever yours is. You may specify more than one tag eg `["-tags=linux,tag1,tag2,etc"]`.

This worked out for me but if it doesn't you may find other unfortunate souls  dealing with this [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29202) and hope someone has a solution for a similar enough environment to yours.

Answer (score 0):

After almost pulling my hair out, I found that linting was working but I had many files with errors. I haven't yet found the hierarchy followed but fixing problems in one file subsequently led to it correctly linting another file. I think it follows the execution tree, although I haven't validated this.
I found this annoying as it can mistakenly lead you to think that linting is not working, while in fact, it's lining a file that you're not currently focussed on, especially if you have generated files that you're not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be that you need to have the folder opened in VS Code with the go.mod file included. So you might have a folder structure that looks like workspace/application/modules/xyz.go. If you have the go.mod file in the application folder and modules is the folder you have open in VS Code it will complain.