# VSCode: Could not import Golang package

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, go-packages

I'm writing a Go project inside my GoPath, and i'm using the Redigo package for connecting to a Redis Server. The application runs fine, however in VSCode there is this annoying error on package import, which is preventing VSCode from giving intellisense suggestions

> Could not import github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis (no package data for import path github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis)

This is my VSCode settings.json

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-great-icons",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.alternateTools": {
        "go-langserver": "bingo"
    },
    "go.toolsEnvVars": {
        "GO111MODULE": "on"
    },
    "go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "documentSymbols": true,
        "findReferences": true,
        "format": true,
        "goToDefinition": true,
        "goToTypeDefinition": true,
        "hover": true,
        "signatureHelp": true,
        "rename": true,
        "workspaceSymbols": true,
    },
    "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
    "go.lintFlags": [
        "--fast",
        "-E", "goimports",
        "-E", "gocritic",
        "-E", "gocyclo",
        "-E", "gosec",
        "-E", "maligned",
        "-E", "scopelint",
        "-E", "interfacer",
        "-E", "goconst",
        "-E", "unconvert",
        "-E", "unparam",
        "-E", "prealloc",
        "-E", "varcheck",
    ],
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false
}
```

I already have the GO111MODULE env var set to on, this is the output of `go env`

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=C:\Users\Francesco\Go\bin
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\Francesco\Go
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\Users\Francesco\Go\src\test\go.mod
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build928398422=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

What should I change to make this work?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

This happens to me in a few specific situations. This is my troubleshooting process :

1. Did you run `go get github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis`?
2. Sometimes I have a similar issue when I open my editor in a root different than my project. (also check the updates at the end of the answer)

```
.  <- editor open here
| 
|_Folder
  | main.go
  | go.mod
  | go.sum
```

3. Make sure your tools are up to date: run `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`, type `Go` and chose `Install/Update tools`.
4. Try moving your project out of the GOPATH, and setting up go.mod for it.
5. Restart the editor

### Update for those with the issue "2":

Go 1.18 has [a new feature](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md#go-workspaces-go-118) called workspace!
If you are opening your workspace in a root different than where your go mod files are, it is probably because you have multiple projects in the same folder. If that is the case, you can run:

```bash
go work init
go work use ./path-to-module  ./path-to-module2
```

What it looks like:

```
.  <- editor open here
| go.work
| app (folder)
  | go.mod
  | go.sum
  | main.go
| client (folder)
  | go.mod
  | go.sum
  | main.go
```

Comment: Looks like updating has solved the issue. I did the go get command before, and the editor was open in the root project folder. I'll try to update the go tools more frequently i guess :P

Comment: this issue has been bugging me for over a year, I've tried everything and your second point about opening the editor in root was the solution I least expected to work, but it did - many thanks

Comment: second part of opening the editor one folder above did the trick for me as well

Comment: This is the definitive solution for developers using VSC with Go modules! Like [Hom Bahrani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4130114/hom-bahrani), I was in a similar situation. Videos on Go and modules did not provide details on how to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: My issue was exactly the point 2:  having opened VSCode on the root of a larger project with many go.mod files inside. Opening the editor workspace into one at the time solved it for me

Comment: Same for me - I need vscode to have the root folder of the project open. Is there no way for us to be able to have multiple go.mod projects open at once?

Comment: Resolved ! I open VSCode as Open Folder at where main.go and go.mod are. IntelliSense can locate the place where a local module is e.i  ...../mod/pkg/<module_name>

Comment: #3 worked for me - for whatever reason, updating the tools removed it. Many thanks!

Comment: for me, open folder at the project root does not work, i ended up created a folder wrap the current folder, and open the VSC from newly created one, works like charm....

Comment: The update worked like a charm

Answer (score 37):

I had a same sort of issue with a different package (on mac),

1. Update the go tools -
   `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` or `cmd` + `shift` + `p` and update/install go tools
2. Restart VScode

Issue solved

Comment: Thank you. now name is "Go: install/Update Tools".

Comment: Thanks, after update, it gives more clear error message, telling me I should put my project inside GOPATH, I can import local package without error in VScode

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar problem, but the situation is slightly different.
I encountered this problem in VSCode remote, and even the basic library like `net/http` cannot be imported.
I found that it was because of some syntax errors in other files under the same package, such as `undefined variables`.
When I solved these syntax errors and restarted VSCode, I found that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

`go mod init package_name` followed by `go mod tidy` got things working for me. `go mod tidy` installed the packages and updated the mod file.

Answer (score 4):

Doing a full restart of vsCode fixed the issue for me.

Note `cmd` + `shift` + `p` -> `Developer: Reload Window` did NOT fix it, only a full close and re-opening of VS code

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. File/New Window
2. File/Add Folder To Workspace ...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when I had two files in one package that had different package names. Eg: one file had `package main` while the other had `package app`.

Ensuring all files have the same package name will result in imports across the package to start working again.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed on Fedora 35 [gcc-go](https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/gcc-go-11.2.1-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html) and after I uninstalled it all worked fine.

```
sudo dnf remove gcc-go
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms. In my case, the root cause was the missing "CGO_ENABLED=1". Cause I had some "C" code in the package.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently ran into this same error, my solution was ensuring that my go version of my project's mod file was the same version as the installed version on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it was from `go mod init packegeName` and a named my package 'time' and the editor give me err so I simply replace it with 'timee' i do not know whats happen actually but it's working fine

Comment: When posting answers to stackoverflow, it's important to keep them concise and brief -- stackoverflow is not a forum to post messages, it's a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Go 1.18+, here is a new feature for multi-module workspaces,
once you setup the go.work file at you root project folder, the issues will no longer exist, you can check the following links for more details

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485684/7706503
2. https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, reinstalled go with goenv, and then i ran some `go mod why`s to check if everything is in order and it was

Answer (score 0):

> ## Setting up your workspace
>
> `gopls` supports both Go module and GOPATH modes. However, it needs a
> defined scope in which language features like references, rename, and
> implementation should operate.
>
> The following options are available for configuring this scope:
>
> ### Module mode
>
> #### One module
>
> If you are working with a single module, you can open the module root
> (the directory containing the `go.mod` file), a subdirectory within
> the module, or a parent directory containing the module.
>
> **Note**: If you open a parent directory containing a module, it must **only** contain that single module. Otherwise, you are working with multiple modules.
>
> #### Multiple modules
>
> Gopls has several alternatives for working on multiple modules
> simultaneously, described below. Starting with Go 1.18, Go workspaces
> are the preferred solution.
>
> ##### Go workspaces (Go 1.18+)
>
> Starting with Go 1.18, the `go` command has native support for
> multi-module workspaces, via
> [`go.work`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces) files. These files are
> recognized by gopls starting with `gopls@v0.8.0`.
>
> The easiest way to work on multiple modules in Go 1.18 and later is
> therefore to create a `go.work` file containing the modules you wish
> to work on, and set your workspace root to the directory containing
> the `go.work` file.
>
> For example, suppose this repo is checked out into the `$WORK/tools`
> directory. We can work on both `golang.org/x/tools` and
> `golang.org/x/tools/gopls` simultaneously by creating a `go.work`
> file:
>
> ```
> cd $WORK
> go work init
> go work use tools tools/gopls
> ```
>
> ...followed by opening the `$WORK` directory in our editor.

---

[Source](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/2e0ca3aded9465405194f01b5523bed9f49f16d8/gopls/doc/workspace.md#setting-up-your-workspace)

Comment: I noticed `go work use dirName` may not work if `dirName` fails silently if it doesn't have a `go.mod` file

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had the root folder (*My Parent folder*) which was the parent of my Go project folder open in VSCode

Ie,

```
My Parent folder
    My Go Project folder
```

Instead of opening the parent folder (*My Parent folder*) you could just open the project folder (*My Go Project folder*)

In my case, I needed access to files in both folders, so I added both parent & child folders to the VSCode workspace [as per here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125674) and this got rid of the errors

Answer (score 0):

If this is a repo that you have pulled from Github, and you are faced with the errors of a `package/s could not be imported` **and** have a `go.mod` in the repo, I did the following to fix:

1. Open terminal and navigate to the root of the project where your `go.mod` and `go.sum` are located and run:

```bash
go mod download
```

Which as the go help menu outlines that the command: `downloads modules to local cache`

2. Inside VS Code open the command palette with whatever command that you have for your architecture. For mine command on mac I use `control + shift + p` and search for `Go: Install/Update tools`. Press enter and update your go tooling.

After that my `main.go` updated with packages that I was missing without explicitly running `go install thingVSCodeSaidIWasMissing`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm newbie with Golang, I don't know the consequencies of these
> commands in bigger project.

In my case, the problem was that I moved the probject to a subfolder. I had to delete go.mod and go.sum, and do `go mod init package_name` followed by `go mod tidy`